# Problem compiling K&R example

Tags: c

I'm having trouble compiling the example program presented in section 5.11 of the book. I have removed most of the code and left only the relevant stuff.

```
#define MAXLINES 5000
char *lineptr[MAXLINES];

void qsort1(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *));
int numcmp(char *, char *);

main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numeric = 1;
    /* ... */
    qsort1((void**) lineptr, 0, 100, (int (*)(void*, void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));
}

void qsort1(void *v[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *)) {
    /* ... */
}

int numcmp(char *s1, char *s2) {
    /* ... */
}
```

The problem is that the code doesn't compile (I'm using Digital Mars compiler). The error I get is this:

```
        qsort1((void**) lineptr, 0, nlines - 1, (int (*)(void*, void*))(numeric
? numcmp : strcmp));

                 ^
go.c(19) : Error: need explicit cast to convert
from: int (*C func)(char const *,char const *)
to  : int (*C func)(char *,char *)
--- errorlevel 1
```

There must be something wrong with the declarations although I pasted the code from the book correctly. I don't know enough to make the right changes (the section about the function pointers could certainly have been written more extensively).

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I'm reading the ANSI version of the book.

Comment: are you compiling as a C program or C++ program

Comment: i could imagine that old K&R code didn't know const. try defining your function as int numcmp(char const*s1, char const*s2) { }

Comment: @litb: this seems to have worked.

Comment: sadly, they put "ansi certified" or whatever on the cover, but yet not all code is compliant apparently :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the error comes from the fact that old C did not know const yet: strcmp there took two pointers to non-const characters (`char *`) i think (which could be the reason why it compiled back then, but not with your compiler). However, nowadays strcmp takes `char const*` (`const char*` is the same thing). Change your function prototype to this:

```
int numcmp(char const*, char const*);
```

Comment: qsort1() signature needs to change too ;)

Comment: indeed there is many stuff to worry about. he should give numcmp's parameters void*, void* instead of pointer to char. but he wanted to get the example from the book to compile. i didn't want to change the whole code of the book's example

Answer (score 2):

The standard function pointer expected by `qsort()` or `bsearch()` has the prototype:

```
int comparator(const void *v1, const void *v2);
```

The `qsort1()` defined in the code expects:

```
int comparator(void *v1, void *v2);
```

The comparator functions defined in the code do not have that prototype, and there is no automatic conversion between different function pointer types.

So, fixes for `qsort1()` are either:

1. Introduce a cast: `(int (*)(void *, void *))`, or
2. Rewrite the comparators:

   ```
   int numcmp(void *v1, void *v2)
   {
       char *s1 = v1;
       char *s2 = v2;
       ...
   }

   int str_cmp(void *v1, void *v2)  // Note new function name!
   {
       return(strcmp(v1, v2));
   }
   ```

Obviously, the call to `qsort1()` would reference `str_cmp` instead of `strcmp`. The authors sought to avoid an intermediate function, but run foul of the (legitimately) fussier compilers in use nowadays.

The standard version of `qsort()` would require a bunch of `const` qualifiers, as in the first version of this answer.

Comment: He is using a custom function called qsort().

Comment: Well, yes: qsort1() to be pedantically pedantic.  And that qsort1() has a different expectations; I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

That's a common problem :)

The following line tells `qsort` to expect a pointer to a function with two void* parameters. Unfortunately, `strcmp` takes two non-modifiable strings hence it's signature is

```
int (*comp)(const char*, const char*)
```

instead of what you have:

```
int (*comp)(void *, void *)
```

Change the signature of both `qsort1` and `numeric`:

```
qsort1(void *v[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(const void *, const void *))
```

and:

```
int numcmp(const char*, const char*)
```

Comment: The signature of qsort1() you wrote is already identical to the one in my example.

Comment: I realised that about a minute and a half before you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Note that `strcmp` takes two **const** arguments, whereas your `numcmp` does not.  Therefore, the two functions' types do not match, and the `? :` operator will complain.

Do one of:

1. change `numcmp` to match the `strcmp` prototype in terms of constness
2. push the `(int (*)(void*, void*))` cast inside the `? :`, e.g.

   ```
   numeric ? (int (*)(void*, void*))numcmp : (int (*)(void*, void*))strcmp
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Its been awhile since I have done any pure C programming, I'm not certain on the new standard.

However casting to void ** creates a pointer to a pointer where the function requires a pointer to an array.  Sure, they are the same thing internally, but strong typechecking will catch that as an error.

rewrite the qsort to accept ** instead of *[] and you should be ok.

Comment: well he already accepts ** . *foo[] in a function prototype will give it the same type as **foo :) that is not teh error but it is often mistaken by programmers