# Pointer type mismatch warning in example from K&R C

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem compiling K&R example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616906/problem-compiling-kr-example)

Lately I have been working my way through the C Programming Language by K&R.

In section 5.11 they cover pointers to functions and after typing in their example -- a quicksort implementation where we provide a pointer to the comparison function we want to use -- I'm getting a warning from the compiler: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression.  (My compiler is gcc 4.0.1 on OS X 10.5.6)

The line from the example that triggers the warning is:

```
 qsort((void **) lineptr, 0, nlines-1,
      (int (*)(void*, void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));
```

The program executes without segfaulting, but I like to smoosh every warning I can, or at least understand their causes.

The function declaration for numcmp looks like:

```
 int numcmp(char *, char *);
```

But according to the manpage, stcmp has this signature:

```
 int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

Is the warning simple because of the slightly different method signatures?  What are the consequences of ignoring the warning?

Comment: Dana, check out [Problem compiling K&R example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616906/problem-compiling-kr-example/616929) and you will probably find the answer to your question there. Let us know if you don't.

Comment: Eddie pointed about a dupe. I voted to close my own question but I thought there would be a way the owner could summarily close it.

Answer (score 6):

Although you can implicitly cast a char* to a void*, you can't do the same for a function pointer with those types (without a warning). The compiler is more careful with type matching on function signatures.

Not to mention that what's happening inside qsort would be the opposite: that is, a void* would be cast to a char* in numcmp and const char* in strcmp.

And the compiler should issue a warning in these cases. If you really have to use a function that doesn't have the same types as parameters, perhaps you should use a wrapper function that does match the types, and then does the appropriate explicit cast when calling the original function.

For instance:

```
static int strcmp_wrapper(void* s1, void* s2) {
  return strcmp((char*)s1, (char*)s2);
}

static int numcmp_wrapper(void* n1, void* n2) {
  return numcmp((char*)n1, (char*)n2);
}

qsort((void **) lineptr, 0, nlines-1,
      (numeric ? numcmp_wrapper : strcmp_wrapper));
```

And the modern signature for qsort is

```
void
qsort(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width,
      int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

The issue of `const` doesn't seem to come into play in your question, but K&R did not have `const`.

Comment: Another option is to change the ternary expression to the following:

numeric ? (int (*)(void *, void *))numcmp : (int (*)(void *, void *))strcmp);

So simply passing the two different functions separately to qsort. This will also avoid any warnings given by the compiler

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: K&R didn't know C.

Long answer: They were handicapped by the fact that when they started, *no one* knew C, so they were sort of making it up as they went along.

(Slightly) less flippant form of the long answer: The language has evolved (some would say *changed*) quite a bit since K&R was written, but unless you got the e-book version with the dynamic example morphing, the examples in your copy of K&R won't have kept up with the "new and approved" ("now with even more ANSI!") language.

Answer (score 1):

One way to try and diagnose it is to see what happens if you replace the expression with the ?: with just one of the two.

If it only happens for strcmp and not numcmp, then it could very well be because of the const char*. I think that while char* can always be converted to void*, you can't convert const char* to void* as "safely".

If it is with both, then perhaps this is about some issue with function pointers, where having the char* converted to void* works, but the signatures should be identical and having voids instead of chars are a problem.